# Bibliography is not order by appearance

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I have my document with my `.bib`. My problem is that I can't figure it out how can I do to have the numbers of the references ordered by appearance.

For instance when I cite `\cite{website:Victhom}` it is the reference number 4 to be cited but instead it appears like [8]

**EDIT**: One thing I have noticed is that this particular link appears in my bibliography in position nº8. Maybe that helps to find the reason

**EDIT 2**: Is the same result if I include the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` line or not

I include the bibliography like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

And this is my .bib:

```
@article{r14,
    Author = {example1},
    Journal = {321},
    Pages = {6421--6424},
    Title = {"some title"},
    %Volume = {35},
    Year = {2010}}     


@book{x20,
    Author = {example 2},
    Publisher = {Wiley - IEEE Press},
    Title = {title 2},
    Year = 2004}


@book{Knuth84,
    Author = {Donald E. Knuth},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Title = {The {\TeX}book},
    Year = 1984}    

@book{handbook,
    Author = {David Linden and Thomas B. Reddy},
    Publisher = {McGraw Hill},
    Title = {Handbook of batteries 3d Ed.},
    Year = 1986}  

@inproceedings{R14,
    Author = {authors},
    Booktitle = {title},
    Title = {"title"},
    Year = {Aug. 31 2010 - Sept. 4 2010}} 


@manual{doc:natbib,
    Author = {Patrick W. Daly},
    Month = feb,
    Title = {Naural Sciences Citations and References},
    Year = {2007}}

@manual{doc:QLSeries,
    Author = {Quallion LLC},
    Month = "",
    Title = {QL-series medical grade rechargeable lithium-ion batteries datasheets},
    Year = {}}

@misc{website:xfab,
      author = "",
      title = "",
      month = "",
      year = "",
      url = "http://www.xfab.com"
}

@misc{website:Victhom,
      author = "Victhom",
      title = "some products",
      month = "",
      year = "",
      url = "http://www.victhom.com"
}

@misc{website:Medtronic,
      author = "Medtronic",
      title = "title",
      month = "",
      year = "",
      url = "http://www.medtronic.com/neuro/gastro/enterra/enterra.html"
}

@misc{website:EpilepsyFoundation,
      author = "Epilepsy Foundation",
      title = "Epilepsy Treatment",
      month = "",
      year = "",
      url = "http://www.epilepsyfoundation.org/about/treatment/vns/"
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The style `unsrt` should order the items in order of appearance. Are you sure this item is the 4th to appear in your document, and not the 8th? It would help if you could reduce your problem to a minimal compilable example (including the main document as well).

Comment: I think I'm having a problem with the `unsrt` style because if I don't include the line it produces the same result. To use `unsrt` I copy the content from [this link](ftp://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/unsrt.bst) to a file and name it unsrt.bst. Shouldn't I do that?

Comment: Depending on your latex distribution, it may be unnecessary. What may happen is that you have another `\bibliograpystyle` command in your file that you forgot about... In that case there should be an error message in the mood of "Ignoring bibliography style unsrt due to previous definition". As I said above in either case, it's hard to diagnose accurately your problem without a complete (and as minimal as possible) example to work on.

Comment: I get the behavior if I add to the document the command `\nocite{*}`, but also an error regarding the `r14` entry (the `%` is *not* a comment character in a `.bib` file) and one about the `R14` entry: BibTeX doesn't like two keys that differ only by capitalization.

Comment: I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168085/bibtex-not-in-appearance-order) answer very usefull

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using a Spanish Thesis. To use it I downloaded a sample thesis. Checking the documents in the sample I found one named ezspanish.bst. The rear thing is that I couldn't find where this bst was called.

So I change the name of my unsrt.bst to ezspanish.bst and now it is working fine.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{ezspanish}`