# BibTeX not in appearance order?

Tags: bibtex

I have a `.bib` file. I am citing the references in the `.bib` file. However, the automatic numbering does not follow the same order as their appearance order. I have something like

> My first reference is popping up very soon [1]. My second reference is
>   supposed to be 2, but it is 3 [3].

I am using the IEEE conference paper template, i.e.,

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

and I am not using any citation package.

My reference section looks like

```
{\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{paper}}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example that isolates this problem?

Comment: Please indicate which bibliography style you're using, and which citation-management packages (e.g., `natbib`, `harvard`, `apa`, etc), if any, you're loading.

Comment: @cslstr I've tried, but failed. In the original case, I have a separate .bib file. So I am not sure how I can provide the MWE.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should be using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}` with `IEEEtran`.

Comment: @cslstr exactly! This solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `IEEEtran` [documentation](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) (pg 15):

> C. Bibliographies
>
> Bibliographies are most easily (and correctly) generated
>   using the IEEEtran BIBTEX package which is easily
>   invoked via
>
> ```
> \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
> \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
> ```
>
> See the [IEEEtran BIBTEX package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) (Section III.) for more
>   information.